# Jsch sftp operation and TIMED_WAITING at java.io.PipedInputStream.read

Tags: java, multithreading, sftp, jsch

I am facing issue with sftp server its responding slow.
I am having 6 parallel session to sftp server and each session have 7 sftp channel to download the files this is done concurrently using thread pool executor. 
Every 8 minute we check the sftp server to get the new files if any.
in every session we connect and disconnect to sftp server.

```
sftpSession.getSession("user","someip");
sftpSession.setTimeout(60000);


getChannel(Session session)
{
 ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
 channels.add(channel);
 channel.connect();
 return channel;
}
```

I could see in thread dumps all threads waits with the same thread stack traces:

```
ftp_list_n [0x00007fedf0308000]
 prio=10 tid=0x00007fedf0308000 nid=0x5c44 in Object.wait() [0x00007feac0120000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:327)
    - locked <0x0000000795e017d0> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378)
    - locked <0x0000000795e017d0> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:3156)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:3182)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.access$500(ChannelSftp.java:37)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2.read(ChannelSftp.java:1391)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000007e35d8288> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
........................................................
```

Comment: Why? You won't get any more value out of 42 paralllel connections than you will get out of one. What exactly is the point?

Comment: @EJP OP can get indeed get more throughput form parallel connections, but 42 is really an overkill. And multiple channels in a single SSH connection won't help either.

Comment: with multi channel I saw the improvement in the download time but now after some time there is slowness is it because of multi channel?
is there any limitation of sftp server with channel in a session.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Once he saturates the bandwidth there is no improvement, and a single connection can saturate the bandwidth.

Comment: @EJP Yes. But you have to have 100% efficient implementation of the SSH/SFTP protocol on BOTH sides for that. And you never have that!  See for example http://serverfault.com/q/694062/168875